# How to deploy data from Django WebApp to a cloud database which can be accessed by Jupyter notebook such as Kaggle?

Tags: django, cloud, jupyter

I have build a Django WebApp. It has an sql database.  I would like to analyze this data and share the analysis using online platform Jupyter notebook such as Kaggle.

I have already deployed to Google App Engine as an SQL instance, but I don't know how to view this SQL instance tables in Kaggle.  There is an option to view BigQuery databases in Kaggle, but I don't know how to get the data from my SQL instance to BigQuery.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to access the data with Kaddle you would need to import the data from the CloudSQL instance into BigQuery.

Currently there are some options for [importing data into BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data#loading_data_from_other_google_services), the best choice would depend on what type of analysis you want to do with it.

If you just want to import the data from the CloudSQL instance into BigQuery, the easiest way to do it would be to first [export the data in CSV format](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/exporting#csv) and then [import the CSV file into BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-local).

In case you are working with a large database, you can also do it programmatically by using the [Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-local#loading_data_from_a_local_data_source).